# Ansible Convert list of dicts to list of lists concatinating values into one string

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to convert list of dicts with keys **ip** and **port**  into list of list where values will be concatenated values **ip:port**.
I have list of dicts in Ansible:

```yaml
 "updated_pool_members_list": [
        [
            {
                "ip": "10.99.99.99",
                "port": 80
            },
            {
                "ip": "10.99.99.100",
                "port": 80
            },
            {
                "ip": "10.99.99.101",
                "port": 80
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "ip": "10.98.98.99",
                "port": 80
            },
            {
                "ip": "10.98.98.100",
                "port": 80
            }
        ]
    ]
```

What I want to get this:

```yaml
    [
     "10.99.99.99:80",
     "10.99.99.100:80",
     "10.99.99.101:80"

    ],
    [  
      "10.98.98.99:80",
      "10.98.98.100:80"
    ]
```

Tried to make two separate lists of IPs and Ports:

```yaml
 - name: Get ip and port into lists
   ansible.builtin.set_fact:
     pool_ip_list: "{{ pool_ip_list + [pool_item | map(attribute='ip') ] }}"
     pool_port_list: "{{ pool_port_list + [pool_item | map(attribute='port') ] }}"
   loop: "{{ updated_pool_members_list }}"
   loop_control:
     loop_var: pool_item
```

Got

```yaml
"pool_ip_list": [
        [
            "10.99.99.99",
            "10.99.99.100",
            "10.99.99.101"
        ],
        [
            "10.98.98.99",
            "10.98.98.100"
        ]
    ]
```

and

```yaml
"pool_port_list": [
    [
        80,
        80,
        80
    ],
    [
        80,
        80
    ]
]
```

But stuck on concatenating items in list of lists.
Maybe there is a better way how to achieve needed result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using jinja2:

```
- name: "tips1"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    updated_pool_members_list: [[{"ip":"10.99.99.99","port":80},{"ip":"10.99.99.100","port":80},{"ip":"10.99.99.101","port":80}],[{"ip":"10.98.98.99","port":80},{"ip":"10.98.98.100","port":80}]]

  tasks:  
    - name: solution set_fact
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ result | d([]) + [iplist] }}"
      loop: "{{ updated_pool_members_list }}"
      vars:
        iplist: >-
            {%- set ips = [] -%} 
            {%- for d in item -%}
            {{ ips.append(d.ip ~ ':' ~ d.port) }}
            {%- endfor -%}
            {{ ips }}  

    - name: debug users      
      debug:
        var: result
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": [
        [
            "10.99.99.99:80",
            "10.99.99.100:80",
            "10.99.99.101:80"
        ],
        [
            "10.98.98.99:80",
            "10.98.98.100:80"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me ! And there is no need to install additional libraries. Furthermore I can use this to solve other actions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way IMO is to use [`jmespath`](https://jmespath.org/) through the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries). Please note from the above doc that this solution requires to have the relevant collections installed as well as `pip install jsmespath` on the controller

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    updated_pool_members_list: [[{"ip":"10.99.99.99","port":80},{"ip":"10.99.99.100","port":80},{"ip":"10.99.99.101","port":80}],[{"ip":"10.98.98.99","port":80},{"ip":"10.98.98.100","port":80}]]

    my_pool_query: "[*][*].join(':', [ip, to_string(port)])"

    my_pool_list: "{{ updated_pool_members_list | json_query(my_pool_query) }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_pool_list
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_pool_list": [
        [
            "10.99.99.99:80",
            "10.99.99.100:80",
            "10.99.99.101:80"
        ],
        [
            "10.98.98.99:80",
            "10.98.98.100:80"
        ]
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```